# Not able to set Initials of <Avatar> based on AsyncStorage value

Tags: react-native, expo, avatar, react-navigation-drawer, react-native-elements

I am building a React Native IOS App and designing a Header in DrawerNavigator with Avatar and want the Initials inside it based on user logged-in.

Below is the Drawer Header component which is attached to main Navigator.

DrawerHeader.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Platform, TouchableOpacity, Image, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react- 
native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class DrawerHeader extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        userName: null
    };
    this._loadDataFromAsyncStorage();
}

_loadDataFromAsyncStorage = async () => {
    const userNameData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userDatauserid');
    const obj = JSON.parse(userNameData);
  const userName = obj.name;
   
    alert('_bootstrapAsync in drawerheader'+userName); 
   
    this.setState({
      userName : userName
    })
 };
 render() {

{!this.state.userName && this._loadDataFromAsyncStorage()}

if (this.state.userName){
return (
    <View
    style={{
      backgroundColor: '#690040',
      height: 140,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }}
  >
 <View style={styles.avatarview}>
 <Avatar  activeOpacity={0.7} rounded title={this.state.userName} />
 </View>

 <Text style={styles.userNameView}>{this.state.userName}</Text> 
 </View>
);
} else {
    return (
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Text>No User Id</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
}
}

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
avatarview:{
    right:'35%',
    top:'10%',
    backgroundColor:'blue'
  },
  userNameView:{
    right:'35%',
    top:'20%'
  }
 })
```

The Alert in the above code is giving correct output as below:

_bootstrapAsync in drawerheader Poornima

, where Poornima is the name of user.Below is the DrawerNAvigator in my app.

[image: Drawer Navigator]

I want this to be set in Avatar as P inside the square icon as show in the below picture.

[image: AvatarIconExample]

But I am getting the name itself inside the square icon.Can anyone explain how to add state data to the title component of Avatar.Thanks in Advance.

I checked with the code to assign the First character of the userName as below:

title={this.state.userName?.charAt(0)} .But I am getting an error as below:

[image: changing tiltle prop]

Answer (score 1):

Because you are passing whole string, it will display whatever you will pass in `title` props

If you will pass `title={'MD'}`, it will display MD

If you will pass `title={'Michel David'}`, it will show whole name

It is mentioned in document itself https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/avatar

In your case if you want first character only, you can write `title={this.state.userName?.charAt(0)}`

Comment: Yes, your inputs seems correct.But after running the code with the changes you said, the alert is outputting userName but I am getting to following error: TypeError: _this$state$userName.charAt is not a function. (In '_this$state$userName.charAt(0)', '_this$state$userName.charAt' is undefined)

Comment: that is the reason chaining is been used because at first your userName will be blank in state and it can not find charAt function. So please use `this.state.userName?.charAt(0)` and should work.

Answer (score 0):

Due to change in requirements,I used email id in the Drawer Nvigator.It is now taking the character at index 0 and displaying the first letter of emailId inside Avatar Icon.Below is the working code:

DrawerHeader.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, TouchableOpacity, Image, View, Text, StyleSheet } 
from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class DrawerHeader extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        emailId:null
    };
    this._loadDataFromAsyncStorage();
}


_loadDataFromAsyncStorage = async () => {
 const userDatalogin = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userDatalogin");
            const obj = JSON.parse(userDatalogin);
            console.log(obj);
        var emailid = obj.textemailid; 
 
   
    this.setState({
      emailId : emailid,
      
    })
    };

    render() {

    {!this.state.emailId && this._loadDataFromAsyncStorage()}

    if (this.state.emailId){
     return (
    <View
    style={{
      backgroundColor: '#0437F2',
      height: 140,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }}
     >
    
     <Avatar  size='medium'
          rounded 
          backgroundColor='green'
          right='35%'
          top='10%'
          title={this.state.emailId?.charAt(0)} />

     </View>
     <Text style={styles.userNameView}>{this.state.emailId}</Text>   
      </View>
      );
     } else {
      return (
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Text>No User Id</Text>
        </View>
     )
     }
     }
     }

     const styles=StyleSheet.create({
     userNameView:{
     right:'15%',
     top:'20%'
     }
     })
```

I have used emailid instead of username based on change in requirement.Find the below output screen.

[image: DrawerNavigator]